# Gradle Ear plugin should not copy resources into .ear root

Tags: gradle

I have the following folder structure of my gradle module:

```
src
    main
        application
            META-INF
                application.xml
                was.policy
                was.webmodule
        java
        resources
            image.bmp
            logback.xml
            ... other files, properties
        webapp
```

My goal is to build an ear archive, which will contain only Tclient.war and META-INF. However, gradle copies all resource files to the ear root.

Gradle documentation about Ear Plugin says that:

> The default behavior of the Ear task is to copy the content of
> src/main/application to the root of the archive. If your application
> directory doesn’t contain a META-INF/application.xml deployment
> descriptor then one will be generated for you.

So, It's not really clear why it puts resources into the root. Maybe, it work's like the `org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar` task and I should override this behaviour in some way?

Here is my partially build.gradle file:

```
jar {
    description 'Creates tclient.jar'
    archiveBaseName = 'tclient'
    destinationDirectory = file('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib')
    from sourceSets.main.output
    include '**/*'
    include '**/*.properties'
    include '**/*.cmd'
}

ear{
    description = "Ear archive for WebSphere server"
    archiveBaseName = 'Tclient'
    appDirName('src/main/application')

    // workaround to exclude classes from ear root
    rootSpec.exclude('**/de/**')
    rootSpec.exclude('**/org/**')
}

war {
    archiveFileName  = 'Tclient.war'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    webInf {
        from configurations.natives into 'lib/bin'
    }

    // do not put compiled classes inside WEB-INF/classes
    rootSpec.exclude('**/de/**')
    rootSpec.exclude('**/org/**')
    rootSpec.exclude('urlrewrite*.dtd')

    from(jar) {
        into 'WEB-INF/lib'
    }

}


dependencies {
    // Place .war inside .ear root
    deploy files(war)
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible workaround is to exclude redundant resources from the rootspec:

```
ear{
    description = "Ear archive for WebSphere server"
    archiveBaseName = 'Tclient'
    appDirName('src/main/application')

    // workaround to exclude classes from ear root
    rootSpec.exclude('**/de/**')
    rootSpec.exclude('**/org/**')
    
    // workaround 
    rootSpec.exclude('*.properties')
    rootSpec.exclude('*.xml')
    rootSpec.exclude('*.dtd')
    rootSpec.exclude('*.bmp')
}
```

However, I'm finding this workaround a little bit ugly and it's a dirty hack.